How do I sample points within multiple polygons loaded from a kml file in R?
I have a kml file that describes four polygons(the kml file is called "core.kml", and I have put a copy at this link). I would like to choose random points within the area defined by the polygons. Ideally I would like to choose points evenly over the whole area, so choose more points from the larger polygons than the small ones, in proportion to their area. I have borrowed the code from answer 1 here, which works beautifully with the North Carolina polygon (at least when I update it by inserting nc <- st_geometry(nc)).  But with my polygons, the st_sample step always gives this error:

st_as_s2(): dropping Z and/or M coordinate Error in
wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :
Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 15 crosses edge 19

I have tried inserting sf_use_s2(FALSE), but I still get the same error.  The plot command does work, and the polygons look as expected. My code:
core<-st_read("core.kml")
core<-st_geometry(core) 
sf_use_s2(FALSE) 
core.points<-st_sample(core,5) 
plot(core)


evenly spaced is deterministic. Do you want random?

@Friede , it's st_make_valid() that  generates a multipolygon when it tries to fix self-intersections.  @chill, did you draw or generate those shapes yourself? If yes, you might have had some issues with shape editor or with correct point order - https://i.sstatic.net/08H7SuCY.png

Yes, that was meant like a warning. @chill, can you share where core.kml comes from?

@Friede I'm checking with my former student who created the files.  I'm pretty sure she drew them in Google Earth Pro, saved them as kmz's, and then I converted to kml.  But I shot her off an email and will update when I hear back.  Neither of us came into this project with any experience with spatial analyses - very much learning as we go.  Your solution was great!  But yes, resolving what was wrong in the first place would be good, too.

@Friede, yes, she made them in Google Earth Pro.  I will zoom in on them and see if I can spot a problem at that level, by inspecting the edges.

@margusl YES it turns out the original polygons had some folded, overlapping edges.  Once I edited them then the simpler code from the answer I linked in my original question worked.  Thank you both for guiding me to the place to look for the source of the errors I was getting.

If it's about to ensure that there are points on each polygon, you might like to try something along the lines
 library(sf)
 sf_use_s2(FALSE) 
#> Spherical geometry (s2) switched off
 core = st_read("/Users/cara/Desktop/core.kml") |> st_geometry() |> st_make_valid() 

 core 
#> Geometry set for 4 features 
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -79.06133 ymin: 33.69862 xmax: -78.90788 ymax: 33.8351
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((-79.014 33.80998, -79.00692 33....
#> POLYGON ((-79.06133 33.82931, -79.05514 33.8306...
#> POLYGON ((-78.99585 33.78962, -78.99496 33.7901...
#> POLYGON ((-78.91353 33.70372, -78.91197 33.7052...
 
 ppwa = \(sfc, pts) { 
   # points per weighted area 
   a = st_area(sfc)
   p = proportions(a)
   as.numeric(p * pts) 
 }
 
 # ensure sum(n) == pts, see below
 floor_preserve = \(x) {
   fx = floor(x)
   i = tail(order(x - fx), round(sum(x)) - sum(fx))
   fx[i] = fx[i] + 1
   fx
 }
 
 n = ppwa(core, 25) |> floor_preserve()
 n 
#> [1] 14  2  6  3
 sum(n)
#> [1] 25
 
 set.seed(1119)
 p = st_sample(core, n)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they
#> are planar
#> ... gets repeated ...

 plot(core) 
 points(p, pch = 4, col = palette.colors()[7])
#> Warning in st_centroid.sfc(x, of_largest_polygon = of_largest_polygon):
#> st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data


Notice that (1) we haven't corrected issues with core. Please have a look on the warnings. This might be a good discussion to start your research; islands are difficult; (2) the total number of points is not random, as we set it to 25. The number of points per polygon is therefore not random randon: it's 25 multiplied by the relative area of each polygon, i.e. weighted.
